# android emulator disconnection issues with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, rest, android-emulator, netbeans-7

I'm working on an authentication android application with eclipse , this application is about consuming a rest web service implemented with netbeans.
when I run the android application in eclipse , the emulator is launched but the application is not running and I get this emulator problem saying :

```
emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.android.RestWSTestActivity activity launch'!
```

and when I close netbeans and rerun the android application with eclipse the emulator runs the application .The problem that I need netbeans to be opened because it contains ths rest web service deployment (glassfish), so how I can I fix this ? is there any configuration or port number to change ??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution ,The problem was that Both Netbeans and Eclipse were pointing on the same android  SDK location , so to solve that , I had to change the netbeans pointing SDK to a different location .
Another possible solution is to disable the android plugin of netbeans so that eclipse emulator will work properly :)